# Para Que Serve a Class no Python

Tags: python

Sou novo em programação mas tem uma coisa que não entendo. Para que serve a `class` em Python?

Por que me parece que com função eu consigo fazer tudo sem usar `class`. Já revirei a net, porém não encontrei nada. Alguém pode me ajudar a entender qual a função de `class` em Python com algum exemplo básico?

Comment: Sua pergunta não envolve só python, é o velho paradigama programação Funcional X OO

Comment: @IsvaldoFernandes A resposta até é boa, mas acho que ele quer uma resposta na pratica, com exemplos mostrando "situações" e explicando. Ao menos é isso o que parece :)

Comment: Acho um tão fácil explicar, Nosso mundo não é Linear/funcional, Precisamos descrever os processos e usar a modelagem para melhor representar nossos objetivos quando programamos, tudo ao nosso redor é cheio características e ações, programação OO é o modelo mais próximo da nossa realidade.

Comment: @IsvaldoFernandes Me lembro dessa pergunta em outro lugar sobre PHP (mesma questão por que classes), a resposta a *principio* seria algo como: é difícil entender porque usar `class` quando "funções resolvem", a verdade é que a `class` pode compartilhar uma variável entre várias funções/métodos dentro da classe e entregar um resultado especifico em outro método e cada método chamado pode resultar em uma resposta diferente, claro que tem bem mais coisas, mas talvez alguém formule uma resposta mais clara é um pouco difícil de explicar.

Answer (score 17):

A função das classes é unir **estrutura** com **comportamento** de uma forma lógica:

- Listas, dicionários, tuplas, etc descrevem uma **estrutura de dados**. Elas podem ser mais ou menos semânticas, mas são suficientes para agrupar dados comuns. Mas os dados em si não fazem nada, eles apenas existem...
- Funções, procedimentos, lambdas, etc descrevem uma **funcionalidade**, ou seja, algo a ser feito, algo que muda o estado interno do computador. Elas podem receber dados como entrada, devolver dados como saída, ter efeitos colaterais em outros dados, acessar *streams*... Entretanto, cada função é um procedimento isolado, desacoplado dos dados individuais nos quais ela opera (a não ser que sejam dados globais).

As classes unem ambos em um único conceito - o **objeto** - que ao mesmo tempo possui dados organizados de forma semântica e também métodos que atuam nesses dados de forma organizada. Isso permite que você trate a classe como um **tipo**, tal como os tipos existentes na linguagem (um número pode ser somado, subtraído, multiplicado, dividido, uma string pode ser concatenada, etc; um objeto da classe `C` pode sofrer as operações `X`, `Y` e `Z`).

E da mesma forma que uma classe pode definir um tipo, outra classe pode definir um **subtipo** (i.e. um tipo mais específico, um subconjunto por assim dizer), *reutilizando* a estrutura e funcionalidade da superclasse (o tipo mais geral) e acrescentando sua própria.

Há diversos outros detalhes no conceito de classe, alguns aplicáveis a Python e outros não (ex. Python não possui encapsulamento), mas os fundamentos são esses. É perfeitamente possível programar sem usar classes [definidas por você], e em alguns casos mais simples é até recomendável, na minha opinião (como tudo mais, classes são ferramentas, para serem usadas quando são úteis e deixadas de lado quando não são). Mas conhecê-las e saber reconhecer quando usá-las vai trazer benefícios, seja na clareza, concisão, semântica, etc, vai te dar um recurso a mais para lidar com a complexidade inerente aos sistemas computacionais.

Answer (score 1):

Em Python, a declaração *class* define uma *classe*.

Em Python, classes são basicamente dicionários que também podem conter funções e permitem que tais funções compatilhem as referências dos elementos do dicionário.

Agora falando de modo mais amplo, classe é um conceito de um paradigma de programção chamado *orientação a objetos*.

Não vou inventar a roda. Existem boas explicações sobre orientação a objetos por aí:

- [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_a_objetos)
- [Clube do Hardware](http://www.hardware.com.br/artigos/programacao-orientada-objetos/)
- [Khan Academy](https://pt.khanacademy.org/search?page_search_query=design%20orientado%20a%20objeto)
- Google/Youtube? =)