# Um módulo é a mesma coisa que uma classe em Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, módulo-python

Um módulo é a mesma coisa que uma classe?

Se não quais são as diferenças? Pergunto isto porque segundo o *The Zen of Python*, devem ser usados módulos em vez de `if`s.

O problema é que após pesquisar pareceram-me o mesmo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Module

A grosso modo um [módulo](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/modules.html) em Python é um arquivo com membros. Um módulo pode conter classes, funções e variáveis "soltas". **Módulos são unidades organizacionais** e usam um conceito de modularização.

Um módulo pode ser importado dentro de outros módulos fazendo que todos seus membros (`import modulo`) ou alguns selecionados (`from modulo import classe`) estejam disponíveis.

A primeira forma de importação apenas torna os membros disponíveis, a segunda forma ainda facilita o uso tornando desnecessário na maioria das situações a referência explícita do que está usando, mas também pode criar ambiguidades. Ainda é possível importar todos os membros com a segunda forma usando `from modulo import *`.

O nome de um módulo é o nome do arquivo sem a extensão `.py`.

Existe ainda um conjunto de módulos organizados em diretórios formando o que se chama pacotes (*packages*).

## Class

[Classes](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/classes.html) servem para criar tipos, para estruturar como objetos serão definidos. Classes possuem estado e comportamento relacionado ao estado, ou seja elas possuem propriedades e métodos que fazem ações relacionadas muitas vezes manipulando as propriedades existentes na classe. **Classes são estruturas de dados** e usa um conceito de orientação a objeto.

Classes podem ser instanciadas, ou seja, é possível criar objetos e guardá-los em variáveis com base no que foi definido nela. A classe é um modelo a ser seguido, é como se fosse uma planta baixa de uma casa e o objeto será a casa construída.

Tecnicamente classes podem ser usadas também como unidades organizacionais. Neste caso a classe não deveria ser instanciada e provavelmente só teria métodos de classe e variáveis estáticas. Mas este não é o jeito pitônico de fazer já que a linguagem permite obter o mesmo resultado com módulos.

Os membros "normais" de uma classe só podem ser acessados através de uma instância. Eles não existem até que um objeto seja criado com base na classe.

Classes podem ter subtipos, ou seja, pode ter herança e criar uma hierarquia de tipos.

Para usar uma classe basta chamar um construtor dela que se confunde com seu próprio nome:

```
funcionario = Funcionario("João", 2000) //está criando um objeto com base na classe Funcionario
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/OOP/InstanceExample.py).

[Artigo na Wikipedia sobre classes](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classe_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)).

## Conclusão

De uma certa forma podemos dizer que os módulos são sobrenomes para as classes e outros membros que formam uma mesma família.

Talvez a ideia de que são a mesma coisa vem do fato que ambos possuem membros (variáveis e funções) mas a forma como eles serão acessados é bem diferente. Para facilitar o entendimento pode-se imaginar um módulo como sendo uma classe que não pode ser instanciada. De fato e em algumas linguagens o módulo é exatamente isto. Não é bem o caso de Python, mas se este pensamento mais ajuda do que atrapalha o seu entendimento, use-o.

Não sei onde você leu que módulos devem ser usados no lugar de `ifs`, isto parece ter tanto sentido quanto usar gasolina no lugar de aço para fazer um *milk-shake*. De fato isto já é esquisito considerando o título da pergunta que faz sentido e usei-o para responder. Talvez alguma comparação tenha sido feita para facilitar o entendimento e causou mais confusão.

Answer (score 4):

Não. [Módulo](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) pode ser definido como um arquivo que contém definições de variáveis, funções e *classes*, criar um módulo pode ser útil em situações que você necessite utilizar as mesmas funções e/ou classes em outros projetos sem ter a necessidade de escrevê-los em cada um.

Veja uma demonstração:

```py
# Modulo1  
# Define variaveis
var1 = 1
var2 = 2

# Define algumas funcoes
def ola():
    return "ola!"

def vezesquatro(numero):
    return int(numero) * 4

# Define uma classe
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nome  = raw_input("Qual o seu nome:")
        self.idade = raw_input("Qual a sua idade:")
        self.peso  = raw_input("Qual o seu peso:")
    def info(self):
        print "O nome dele e {0}, tem {1} anos e pesa {2} quilos!".format(self.nome, self.idade, self.peso)
```

Salve o *script* acima como `modulo1.py` e crie um outro *script* e execute o código:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import modulo1       

print (modulo1.var1)
print (modulo1.var2)

ola = modulo1.ola()
print (ola)

quatro = modulo1.vezesquatro(10)
print ("10 x 4 = {0}".format(quatro))

f = modulo1.Foo()
f.info()
```

Já uma [classe](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) é uma estrutura que abstrai um conjunto de objetos que define o comportamento destes através de *métodos* e os estados possíveis destes objetos através de *atributos*.

A [resposta do mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51481/6454) na questão abaixo aborda esse assunto de um modo mais amplo.

- [Para Que serve a Class no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51473/6454)