# Uso de funções no Python

Tags: python, funções, estilo-de-codificação

sei que é possível criar funções no *Python* para realizar determinadas tarefas que normalmente precisam ser executadas diversas vezes dentro de uma aplicação.

---

**Ex:** Programa de uma loja de tinta que calcula a área a ser pintada e a quantidade de tinta necessária.

```
def areaTinta(altura, largura):
    area = altura * largura
    tinta = area / 2
    print('-' * 50)
    print(f'Serão necessários {tinta:.2f}l de tinta para pintar uma parede de {area:.2f}m².')
```

A questão é:

- Funções realmente **só** devem ser usadas em casos
  que há repetição de código?
- É errado usá-las para casos mais simples
  em que não há, por questões de Clean Code ou otimização de sistemas?
- **SE** vier a ser usada "desnecessariamente" quais as consequências
  disso na minha aplicação?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pense em uma função sempre que deseja fazer algo em especifico. Vamos usar seu código como exemplo:

```
def areaTinta(altura, largura):
    area = altura * largura
    tinta = area / 2
    print('-' * 50)
    print(f'Serão necessários {tinta:.2f}l de tinta para pintar uma parede de {area:.2f}m².')
```

A função sua esta a fazer quatro coisas distintas,

1. Calcular a área que vai ser pintada.
2. Calcular a quantidade de tinta necessária.
3. Exibir o `-` cinquenta vezes no console.
4. Exibir a mensagem para o usuário informando a área a ser pintada e a quantidade de tinta que deve ser usada.

Perceba que você atribuiu varias responsabilidades para a sua função `areaTinta()`, veja que o nome por si só da função diz uma *coisa* e a função prova outras *coisas*.

## Abstração

Isolar algo do todo, isolar as operações contidas na sua função `areaTinta()`. Isso se aplica como uma forma de generalização, seja com parâmetros ou não. E tendo em mente que a função faz uma *única* coisa, podemos isolar algumas partes do *todo*.

Veja o exemplo:

```
def calcularArea(altura, largura):
    return altura * largura

def calcularQuantidadeTinta(area):
    return area / 2
```

Dividi sua função `areaTinta()` em duas, uma que calcula apenas a área recebendo como parâmetro `altura` e `largura`, e outra que calcula a quantidade dividindo a `area` por `2`, desta forma isolamos o processamento dos dados em funções separadas, dando mais abstração e significado ao código.

E você aparentemente não precisa exibir a mensagem para o usuário dentro da própria função? Como não há contexto, vamos usar a função `print` no escopo global do programa.

Veja:

```
def calcularArea(altura, largura):
    return altura * largura

def calcularQuantidadeTinta(area):
    return area / 2

area = calcularArea(2, 6)
tinta = calcularQuantidadeTinta(area)

print(f'Serão necessários {tinta:.2f}l de tinta para pintar uma parede de {area:.2f}m².')
```

Saída

> Serão necessários 6.00l de tinta para pintar uma parede de 12.00m².

Percebeu a diferença agora no uso de funções?

Perceba que agora as duas funções assumiram responsabilidades únicas, ou seja, fazer uma única coisa. E é interessante que você aprenda mais sobre [abstrações de funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/360571/27190) e estude a respeito do [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120932/27190).

Answer (score 4):

O uso das funções não é apenas para código repetido. Elas podem ser utilizadas para encapsular trechos do código e melhorar a leitura.

Imagine um código que está tratando da solução de um problema e no meio dele é necessária a configuração de um dispositivo pra prosseguir. Por causa da configuração você perde totalmente a linha de raciocínio e atrapalha a compreensão do código. Nesses casos vale encapsular em função.

Por outro lado, encapsulamento desnecessário pode causar desconforto e dificuldade para quem for ler o código. Imagina um código que encapsula tudo em funções e, para você entender, tem que ficar pulando de um lado para o outro. Um exemplo absurdo seria um código para somar dois números e imprimi-los na tela e você fazer uma função para imprimir e outra para somar. Bem desnecessário, não acha?!

No fim, o que define isso é você ao adotar uma forma de apresentação do seu código para melhor expor sua ideia. Você tem sempre que ter em mente que seu programa deve ser inteligível pra quem vier depois. Ter empatia e se colocar no lugar do colega é essencial nessas horas.

Answer (score 2):

As funções ou métodos são muito importantes e servem para dividir o código e mante-lo organizado, quando começamos a criar vários objetos ou módulos (link 1) no Python precisamos dividir os trechos de código para que cada um tenha uma responsabilidade única, essa regra faz parte de um conjunto de regras de boas práticas chamadas de SOLID (link 2). Conforme seu código for crescendo você vai se agradecer por ter feito tudo separado e organizado.
Segue os links para mais informações.

1 - [Um módulo é a mesma coisa que uma classe em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53067/um-m%C3%B3dulo-%C3%A9-a-mesma-coisa-que-uma-classe-em-python)

2 - https://medium.com/equals-lab/princ%C3%ADpios-s-o-l-i-d-o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-porque-projetos-devem-utiliz%C3%A1-los-bf496b82b299