# Usar método sem self no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos

Vi em outros tópicos  algumas discussões sobre passar o `self` como argumento. Mas não me ficou muito claro.

Mesmo que minha função não tenha nenhum argumento para ser iniciado ainda preciso passar o `self` como primeiro argumento?

Por exemplo:

```
class calculadora:
    def somar(n1,n2):
        return n1+n2
    def subtrair(n1,n2):
        return n1-n2

c=calculadora()
print(c.somar(5,4))
```

Essa classe não precisa de `construtor(__init__)` para iniciar nenhum argumento mas o compilador diz que :

> TypeError: somar() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Não vejo fundamento nenhum usar o `self` no método `somar()`, mas é pedido.
Para esse específico caso acima há alguma maneira de se usar o método `somar()` sem passar o `self` para ele?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você quer criar um método então precisa do `self`. O próprio objeto será passado como parte dos argumentos do método, então precisa de algum parâmetro para recebê-lo, e ele é o `self`.

Se você quer só uma função, e em muitos casos é só o que deseja mesmo, inclusive este caso do exemplo da pergunta então não use o `self`, mas também não chame como método, ou seja, não crie um objeto para executar esta função. Na verdade nem crie a classe, afinal classes existem para definir objetos e não há nenhum objeto sendo definido neste código, baste criar funções.

Então está correto em não ter fundamento o uso do `self` aí, mas também não tem fundamento criar uma classes para fazer algo tão simples e sem estado a ser preservado e sem uma consistência clara sobre o seu uso. Produz o mesmo resultado sem dificuldades:

```
def somar(n1, n2):
    return n1 + n2
def subtrair(n1, n2):
    return n1 - n2

print(somar(5, 4))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/NoClass.py).

Você pode por estas funções em um [módulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53067/101) e segregar como parece estar querendo, isso é o mais correto. Mesmo podendo evite criar classes só com métodos estáticos ou em classes normais onde não faça sentido sua presença ali. Nada indica no seu caso que deva usar isto.

Answer (score 6):

É possível fazer o que deseja, mas faça quando tenha ciência do que está fazendo. Bem como o Maniero respondeu, da forma que colocou, parece mais que você só precisa de duas funções, então reveja a necessidade de uma classe.

Porém, no Python, diferente de algumas outras linguagens, a classe nada mais é que uma ferramenta de gerenciamento de contexto, ou seja, é aceitável que você utilize uma classe apenas para empacotar as funções dentro de um escopo isolado de forma que não gere conflitos com o resto da aplicação. Para isso você precisa utilizar métodos estáticos.

```
class Calculadora:

    @staticmethod
    def somar(a, b):
        return a + b
```

Desta forma, sendo um método estático, você não precisa instanciar a classe - a função ("método") pertence à classe, não à instância.

```
>>> Calculadora.somar(1, 2)
3
```

Mas o mesmo gerenciamento de contexto você consegue através dos módulos. Ao criar, por exemplo, um arquivo `calculadora.py` e definir as funções nele:

```
# calculadora.py

def somar(a, b):
    return a + b
```

E na aplicação bastaria importar o módulo, chamando as funções desejadas:

```
>>> import calculadora
>>> calculadora.somar(1, 2)
3
```